scrapy response returns None value
I want to scrapy location coordinate from this page that is under id="hotel_address".
class CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name='crawler'
headers={'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'} 

start_urls=['https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/heart-of-san-lorenzo-roma12345678910111213141516171819202122.it.html?group_adults=1;no_rooms=1;']
#               
def start_requests(self):
     for link in self.start_urls:
         yield scrapy.Request(url=link,headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):  
   coordinate=""
   print('===========================================================')
   coordinate=response.xpath('//*[@id="hotel_address"]/@data-atlas-latlng/text()').get()
   print(coordinate) 
   print('===========================================================')
process=CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(CrawlerSpider)
process.start()

but it returns None value.what is my mistake?

The reason is that you used text(). The data-atlas-latlng attribute contains the coordinates as a value, not as a child text node. To resolve the issue, you need to directly get the value of the data-atlas-latlng attribute using @data-atlas-latlng in your XPath expression.
I provide updated code.
class CrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'crawler'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36'} 

    start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/hotel/it/heart-of-san-lorenzo-roma12345678910111213141516171819202122.it.html?group_adults=1;no_rooms=1;']

    def start_requests(self):
        for link in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('===========================================================')
        # Extract the coordinates from the data-atlas-latlng attribute
        coordinate = response.xpath('//*[@id="hotel_address"]/@data-atlas-latlng').get()
        print(f"Coordinates: {coordinate}")  # Prints the coordinates
        print('===========================================================')

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(CrawlerSpider)
process.start()



It does not work for me. I checked response.text and there is not  "data-atlas-latlng"  at all.

That answers your original question. Now you need to check why it's not there.
